# Подключение нескольких микрофонов к одноплатнику

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, orange-pi

У меня есть задача подключить несколько микрофонов через звуковые карту к одноплатному компьютеру на базе линукс (Debian). Решений в интернете я не нашел. Может быть кто нибудь знает как правильно это сделать?

Comment: Использовать микшерный пульт.

Comment: Я думаю это очень дорого. Можно ли сделать как то проще подключив 8 микрофонов через звуковые карты и как то записать звук с каждого из них.

Comment: Если поставить 8 звуковых карт, то можно подключить 8 микрофонов. Но нужно будет ПО, которое поддерживает 8 звуковых карт и цифровое микширование в компе. И нужно поглядеть что дороже - 8 звуковых карт или 1 внешний микшерный пульт. И да, нужно чтобы еще в компе было место (свободные слоты) для подключения восьми звуковых карт.

Comment: Ну они разные бывают. От 500 на али.

Comment: Звуковые карты я беру самые дешевые, а 8 штук хочу подключить при помощи свича. Вопрос только как работать с 8 микрофонами одновременно.